# Can you make a process pool with shell scripts?

Tags: scripting, process, freebsd, parallelism

Say I have a great number of jobs (dozens or hundreds) that need doing, but they're CPU intensive and only a few can be run at once.  Is there an easy way to run `X` jobs at once and start a new one when one has finished?  The only thing I can come up with is something like below (pseudo-code):

```
jobs=(...);
MAX_JOBS=4;
cur_jobs=0;
pids=(); # hash/associative array
while (jobs); do
    while (cur_jobs < MAX_JOBS); do
        pop and spawn job and store PID and anything else needed;
        cur_jobs++;
    done
    sleep 5;
    for each PID:
        if no longer active; then
            remove PID;
            cur_jobs--;
done
```

I feel like I'm over-complicating the solution, as I often do.  The target system is FreeBSD, if there might be some port that does all the hard work, but a generic solution or common idiom would be preferable.

Comment: GNU Parallel seems to be the tool for this, but I am not sure. It does have [a port](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/parallel/).

Comment: I'd write a makefile for this and then run `make -f 4` for 4 parallel jobs.

Comment: A makefile, that is brilliant. I would've never thought of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have GNU Parallel you can do this:

```
parallel do_it {} --option foo < argumentlist
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: The GNU Parallel page lists [a FreeBSD port](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/parallel/).

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it's tricky and fragile. There are several options, one of them is `xargs`.

The problems encountered when relying on job control and signals are discussed in this interesting article, really a recommended read:

http://prll.sourceforge.net/shell_parallel.html

The guy apparently made a new tool `prll` that can take arbitrary shell functions to execute in parallel (with auto-detected or user-defined pool size), which uses a control process that synchronizes all the input and output.

Check it out here:
https://gitorious.org/prll/pages/Home

Comment: Some of the problems with xargs are described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-xargs-AND-GNU-Parallel Some of the problems with prll are described here http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-prll-AND-GNU-Parallel

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same situation as you, but the jobs I need to run in parallel are commands which run ruby scripts. First I need to admit it's not perfect, instead, it's fragile.

What I did in my ruby code was,

```
counting_process = IO.popen "ps -e | grep 'YourCMDPattern' -c"
count_of_processes = counting_process.readlines[0].to_i
```

Then in a while loop, I'm checking the count of processes periodically, then trigger shell command to run a certain number of new processes with ruby's IO.popen when the count is below the number of parallel execution I want to keep.

Note, the shell command I need to run is dynamic and contains variable generated from ruby code, that's why I have to do it in ruby script.

GNU Parallel seems to be a better option for you if ruby is not involved.